# How to import a UIViewController in AppDelegate using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIViewController` class named FirstViewController.swift which I want to import in AppDelegate.swift in my app named as MySample.How to import a UIViewController.swift in AppDelegate.swift. I googled but couldn't find answers that are working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: U r using story board ya XIB?

Comment: I am using stroryboard. Is there anything like #import "FirstViewController.h" as in Objective C equivalent in Swift

Comment: No, in a Swift project you don't need to import other classes - they are implicitly visible

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var FirstViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardID") as FirstViewController
    rootViewController.pushToViewController(FirstViewController, animated: true)

    return true

  }
```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.